# How to create a dynamic array of strings in C?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I want to make an array of strings in which I don't have a fix lenght for every string. How do i do it?
This is my code:

```
char **a;
int n, m;
scanf_s("%d %d", &n, &m);
a = (char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] = (char*)malloc(m*sizeof(char));

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m;j++)
    scanf_s(" %c", &a[i][j])
```

I have to input an array of words and i don't know the lenght for them. In this code I can input only words of a certain lenght and I want to change that.

Comment: `malloc` a `char**`, and then `malloc` the space needed for each of the strings, storing the pointer to them in respective indices of the array created by the first `malloc`.

Comment: I did that already, but i want to input words o differet lenght.

Comment: What have you done so far, where are you stuck? Show your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because no code.

Answer (score 1):

An example of what @Daniel says is:

```
int NumStrings = 100;
char **strings = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * NumStrings);
for(int i = 0; i < NumStrings; i++)
{
   /* 
      Just an example of how every string may have different memory allocated.
      Note that sizeof(char) is normally 1 byte, but it's better to let it there */
   strings[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * i * 10);
}
```

If you don't need to `malloc` every string at the beginning, you can do it later. If you need to change the number of strings allocated (do a `realloc` to `strings`), then it might be slightly more complicated.

Comment: `char strings = malloc(...)` -> `char**`

Comment: It's just an example. Maybe something smaller is better for you? (edited the answer)

Comment: Sure you can, but you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`, and you definitely shouldn't do it to force the compiler to save the result in a `char`...

Answer (score -2):

Allocate an array of strings char ** mystrs = malloc(numstrings * sizeof(char *)).  Now mystrs is an array of pointers.  Now all you need to do is use malloc for each string you want to add.

mystrs[0] = malloc(numchars +1 * sizeof(char)). // add extra char for null character

Then you can copy the string data with strcpy.
strcpy(mystrs[0], "my string")